# Using FreeIPA for centralized sudo - how to specify ALL commands?

Tags: sudo, freeipa

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around FreeIPA's model. The FreeIPA [manual](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html-single/FreeIPA_Guide/index.html) states:

> FreeIPA adds an extra control measure with sudo command groups, which
>   allow a group of commands to be defined and then applied to the sudo configuration as one.

But their examples basically talk about creating a sudo command group and adding *particular* sudo commands like `vim` and `less` to a "files" sudo command group.

e.g. from the commandline:

```
ipa sudocmdgroup-add --desc 'File editing commands' files

ipa sudocmd-add --desc 'For editing files' '/usr/bin/vim'

ipa sudocmdgroup-add-member --sudocmds '/usr/bin/vim' files
```

But how do you specify `ALL` like you would in /etc/sudoers? Can this be wildcarded (e.g. *)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to make command groups if you want a group of users to be able to execute any command with `sudo`. You just need a sudo rule that permits all commands, and one should have been created for you by default when you installed FreeIPA.

```
# ipa sudorule-find All
-------------------
1 Sudo Rule matched
-------------------
  Rule name: All
  Enabled: TRUE
  Host category: all
  Command category: all
  RunAs User category: all
  User Groups: admins
----------------------------
Number of entries returned 1
----------------------------
```

(If such a rule doesn't exist, create it.)

```
ipa sudorule-add --cmdcat=all All
```

Just add the users or groups to this sudo rule that you want to be able to `sudo` with any command.

```
ipa sudorule-add-user --groups=admins All
```

You can also do this from the Web UI if you prefer.

Comment: The rule didn't exist by default and it took a little bit of work to get a rule that matched yours, i.e. "%admins ALL=(ALL)       ALL" but I think I'm on the path of enlightenment now. Much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is one of those tasks that was obviously much easier in the Web UI than the command line. It took me quite a while to get even that far with it in the CLI.

Comment: Agreed, I finished off the rule in the Web UI.

Comment: If you want the rule to be effective across all hosts, I noticed that without specifying `--hostcat=all` when creating the rule, sudo is not allowed (adding this option to an existing rule is possible by issuing `sudorule-mod --hostcat=all`).

Comment: @HTTP500 If you had to do things that are not listed in your OP or the Accepted Answer, please provide the steps/details for others, i.e. _The rule didn't exist by default and it took a little bit of work to get a rule that matched yours_... What bit of work was required? How did you achieve the desired result?

Comment: Still not fully working for me.  I ran `ipa sudorule-add --cmdcat=all --hostcat=all --runasusercat=all All` then added the group to the rule.  I also added the specific user to the rule.  Anything else I should be doing?

Comment: @wordsforthewise Probably you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to add `ALL` to a rule, you can use category option with value `all`. For commands that would be `--cmdcat=all`, for hosts -- `--hostcat=all`, for users -- `--usercat=all` and few more below.

All these options are visible in `ipa sudorule-add --help`:

```
$ ipa sudorule-add --help
Usage: ipa [global-options] sudorule-add SUDORULE-NAME [options]

Create new Sudo Rule.
Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --desc=STR            Description
  --usercat=['all']     User category the rule applies to
  --hostcat=['all']     Host category the rule applies to
  --cmdcat=['all']      Command category the rule applies to
  --runasusercat=['all']
                        RunAs User category the rule applies to
  --runasgroupcat=['all']
                        RunAs Group category the rule applies to
...
```